# Service can do ,but Asynctask can not?

Tags: android, service, android-asynctask, intentservice

I have read about difference between **Service,Intent Service** & **Asynctask** ,but I have not figured out any situation where only service works but Asynctask fails.

I have noticed some points:

1. Asynctask can be used as bound or started service.
2. Asynctask can run in background,if user switch to different application then too Asynctack will work.
3. Asynctask can send message to our activity.
4. If a component which starts asynctask is destroyed then too asynctask executes in background and we can use its `onPostexecute()` method to start another application component.

So Please tell me some functionalities for which we have to use Service, we cann't implement those with Asynctask.

Comment: Actually I think you can compare Service and Intent Service, but... Asynctask usually works inside Service. AsyncTask isn't indepentend.

Comment: as @soulreaver said, they are different. you can't compare them.

Comment: @soulreaver I am just asking situation when we have to use Service.Can i implement all ,using activity with background work using asynctask.

Comment: Oh, then of course you can't. Read @Adhikari Bishwash's answer.

Answer (score 1):

When your app is destroyed automatically due to low memory or users throws from task manager your async task is also destroyed, but in this same case service will not be destroyed.

Answer (score 0):

> intent service , service are both almost same, you should not compare them. You can compare service asynctask. The difference in service and async service is asynctask is ui-thread blocker but service is not. Service can run completely in background. Its issue more related to user interface design for take a example of login use case, it should happen asynchronously not in  background. Here ui should be waiting cursor for the user, but uploading files can happen in background where user just need to initiate the process and contineuos with other tasks.

hope your clear.